# Auto Reply to Gmail apps for business outside of office hours

Tags: email, gmail-api

I have created the following scripts based on the above to answer emails Mon - Fri before 9am and after 5pm in our Gmail apps for Business.

For whatever reason that I can't see it has not been successful. Any tips. It says it executes, has a 0sec run time, all API's for Gmail are enabled.

I can't help but think it has something to do with the Gmail apps for business as I tested it on my private Gmail and it worked fine.

The First script for weekdays before 9am and after 5pm is

```
function AutoReply() 
{ 
    var interval = 5; 
    var date = new Date(); 
    var day = date.getDay(); 
    var hour = date.getHours(); if ([1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 
    [1,2,3,4,5] && hour < 9) || (day == [1,2,3,4,5] && hour >= 17)) 
    {
        var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
        var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
        for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
        {
            if (threads[i].isUnread()){
                threads[i].reply("Thank you for reaching out to us. Our Customer Support 
                Team is available Monday to Friday between 9am and 5pm. We are looking m 
                forward to helping you with your enquiry during business hours.In the 
                meantime, please check our Frequently Asked Questions page, Delivery page or 
                Returns page for more information which can be found on our website at 
                www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.au and follow the links at the bottom of the 
                page.");
                threads[i].markRead();
                threads[i].markImportant();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weekend version is for Saturday and Sunday at any time

```
function AutoReply() { 
    var interval = 5; 
    var date = new Date(); 
    var day = date.getDay(); 
    var hour = date.getHours(); if ([6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == [6,0] && 
    hour < 24) || (day == [6,0] && hour >= 0))
    { 
        var timeFrom = 
        Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval; var threads = 
        GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom); for (var i = 0; i < 
        threads.length; i++) 
        { 
            if (threads[i].isUnread())
            { threads[i].reply("Thank 
                you for reaching out to us.Our Customer Support Team is available Monday to 
                Friday between 9am and 5pm. We are looking forward to helping you with your 
                enquiry during business hours.In the meantime, please check our Frequently 
                Asked Questions page, Delivery page or Returns page for more information 
                which can be found on our website at www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.au and follow 
                the links at the bottom of the page.");
                threads[i].markRead();
                threads[i].markImportant();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice

Is there an error I am missing in this mess I have created?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by settings in Gmail itself. You will have a predefined options where you can set the auto-respond which will reply in the timeings that you have set.

Comment: Thanks Avid, I was aware of the Auto Responder but I am not sure that it is able to be time sensitive? The Vacation responder can be turned on and off, but I am trying to automate the process to remove the chance of human error.

Comment: Auto Responder is based on the days at which you want to respond automatically. To to this based on timings, you need to have permissions from Gmail I guess. Let us know if this can be automated, so that it will be helpful to the community also.